# Can python queue have access to all processes waiting on a queue?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Here's an example:

```
def food(q,x):
     q.put(x)

q = mp.Queue(1)
p = []
for i in range(100): 
    p.append(mp.Process(target=foo,args=(q,100))
for i in range(len(p)):
    p[i].start()
```

I know there are blocking processes because the queue size only has capacity of 1, and I have not dequeued any elements. However, I want to know if there is any way to figure out what processes are blocking from the perspective of the queue. That is, can the queue figure out/know that processes i to n are waiting to put an element on the queue? Put differently, can one figure out programmatically what processes are waiting to put an object on the queue?

Comment: Maybe you should subclass `Process` and add a method that sets an attribute to `True` before it gets something from the queue and to False when done, then return the item.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where processes are terminating after doing work then you could use `is_alive`:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def foo(q,x):
     q.put(x)

q = mp.Queue(1)
p = []
for i in range(10): 
    p.append(mp.Process(target=foo,args=(q,100)))

for i in range(len(p)):
    p[i].start()

for i in range(len(p)):
    # prints true here
    print(p[i].is_alive())

for i in range(int(len(p)/2)):
    #consume half the queue data
    q.get()

for i in range(len(p)):
    # prints false for ~half here
    print(p[i].is_alive())
```